# Harmonic series "fulfills" Cauchy criterion

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ the $n$-th partial sum in the harmonic series. Once can prove that

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|S_{n+p}-S_n|=0,
$$

for all $p\in\mathbb{N}$. On the other hand, the harmonic series diverges. So the question is why the above limit "fulfills" the Cauchy criterion for series, but the harmonic series still diverges?

The Cauchy Criterion states that for a sequence $(a_n)$ in the complex numbers, $\sum_n a_n$ converges if and only if to each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $q>p\geq n_0$ implies $|\sum_{n=p+1}^q a_n|=|S_q-S_p|<\epsilon$.

Comment: In the first paragraph, that's **not** Cauchy's criterion.

Comment: Simple: the hypothesis of Cauchy criterion is strictly stronger than the condition $[\forall m,\ \lim_{n\to \infty}\lvert a_{n+m}-a_n\rvert=0]$.

Comment: By stronger you mean that for example the Cauchy Criterion is fulfilled _for all_ $q>p\geq 0$, even when e.g. $q=p+1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that for all $p$ and $\varepsilon$ there is some $N_{p,\varepsilon}$ such that, for all $n\ge N_{p,\varepsilon}$, $\lvert a_{n+p}-a_n\rvert\le \varepsilon$.

What you *do not* know is wheter or not for all $\varepsilon$ there is some $N_\varepsilon$ such that, for all $n\ge N_\varepsilon$ and for all $p$, $\lvert a_{n+p}-a_n\rvert\le\varepsilon$.

As of why these need not be equivalent, the instance at hand shows.

Comment: Does this mean that for Cauchy criterion, for any $\epsilon >0$, the N that we are talking about is such that ***for all*** n and p > N, $|{s_{n+p}-s_n}| < \epsilon$, i.e. that after that N, this will hold for partial sum of any number of finite terms?, which would also mean that $|\sum_{n+1}^{n+p} {a_i}| < \epsilon$, again for any number of finite terms after that N?